# How to enable Empathy chat room notifications?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, empathy, notification

Is it possible in Empathy (Ubuntu 11.10, gnome-shell) to receive notifications when somebody posts a message to a chat room?

I have checked the "Enable bubble notifications" box under edit > preferences.

I currently receive notifications for direct messages from my colleagues, but not when somebody posts to the chat room.

Comment: +1 This is so frustrating. We use IRC for our group chat at work.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look to me like there is a way to enable notifications for this, at least not if you're using Unity.

However, you can set sounds to play whenever you receive a message under *Edit > Preferences > Sounds*:

[image: Screenshot of Empathy Preferences window]

However, you *can* have notifications displayed (whether you like it or not) if you use Empathy through GNOME Shell without your chat window being focused. A notification will appear at the bottom of the screen, showing the messages and even allowing you to type a reply.

I realize this amounts to my answer basically being "use sounds instead or switch your session", but that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using gnome-shell. I like the notifications at the bottom of the screen, but my problem is that they do not appear for the chat room.