# No Empathy notifications with Gnome Shell 3.2

Tags: gnome, empathy, notification, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable Empathy chat room notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69335/how-to-enable-empathy-chat-room-notifications)

I installed the Gnome shell 3.2. when I run empathy there is no icon in the notification area (bottom-right) and there's not any notification but a sound.
any help?

Comment: Have the same issue on Debian Testing and my co-worker has it on Arch. It's gotta be a Gnome3 problem.