# How to enable Empathy incoming message notifications?

Tags: lubuntu, empathy, preferences

I installed empathy in Lubuntu.

I want a notification to popup when a message is received.

However, when I open edit -> preferences -> notifications, it doesn't have an option, "show incoming messages in the messaging menu" as usual.

What should I do to enable message notifications?

Comment: What are the version of Lubuntu and Empathy ?

Comment: My Lubuntu version is 12.10 with the latest Empathy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but did you check that `telepathy-indicator` is up and running ?
You might have to install it with::

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telepathy-indicator
```

Then you can launch it on the command line or in the Startup Applications.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.10 with Empathy 3.6.0.3-0ubuntu1.

I have no idea if this is off-topic for Lubuntu...

Comment: I already have `telepathy-indicator` isntalled, but it still work. I think Maybe in Lubuntu's desk LXDE, it just don't have this function. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*In the Preferences window you can only disable/enable the visual notifications.* There is a message notifier extension which is pretty customizable too

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/150/message-notifier/

In case you are still not getting notification then you might try the method described in a previous question.

[How to enable Empathy chat room notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69335/how-to-enable-empathy-chat-room-notifications)

Comment: But lubuntu doesn't use gnome. It use desktop LXDE.

Comment: Then I guess you need to take a look at previous question link given in the same post.

Comment: I don't think question "How to enable Empathy chat room notifications?" help.